# NodeJs: next is not function

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, supertest

I try to write the unit tests using Mocha, Chai and Supertest, but now, unfortunately, unsuccessfully.
I have next route:

```
var express = require('express');
var GoogleUrl = require('google-url');
var _ = require('lodash');
var token = require('../middlewares/token');
var Url = require('../models/url');
var config = require('../config');
var router = express();

router.post('/urls/create', token.required, createShortUrl);

module.exports = router;

function createShortUrl(req, res) {

    _.trim(req.body.list_tags);
    var tags = _.split(req.body.list_tags, ',');
    tags.splice(tags.length - 1, 1);

    var date = returnDate();
    var time = returnTime();

    var googleUrl = new GoogleUrl({
        'key': config.get('google_key')
    });

    googleUrl.shorten(req.body.full_url, function (err, shortUrl) {

        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json(err);
        }

        var url = new Url({
            'author': req.payload.username,
            'description': req.body.description,
            'full_url': req.body.full_url,
            'short_url': shortUrl,
            'list_tags': tags,
            'date': date,
            'time': time
        });

        url.save(function (err) {

            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json(err);
            } else {
                res.status(200).json('Shortener url is created!');
            }

        });

    });

}

   function returnDate() {
    var d = new Date();
    var yyyy = d.getFullYear();
    var mm = d.getMonth() < 9 ? '0' + (d.getMonth() + 1) : (d.getMonth() + 1);
    var dd = d.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + d.getDate() : d.getDate();
    return dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;
}

function returnTime() {
    var d = new Date();
    var hh = d.getHours() < 10 ? '0' + d.getHours() : d.getHours();
    var min = d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes();
    var ss = d.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' + d.getSeconds() : d.getSeconds();
    return hh + ':' + min + ':' + ss;
}
```

I save the data in the MongoDB using Mongoose.
For route I wrote the unit test:

```
var app = require('../server');
var chai = require('chai');
var request = require('supertest');
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var config = require('../config');

var expect = chai.expect;

describe('Urls Tests', function () {

  var url = {
    author : 'Alexey',
    description : 'grrggr',
    full_url : 'https://github.com',
    short_url : 'short_url_by_google',
    date : '30-06-2017',
    time : '18:21:27',
    count_click : 0,
    list_tags : [
      'Sport',
      'Football'
    ]
  };

  var token = {
    required: jwt({
      secret: config.get('jwtSecret'),
      userProperty: 'payload',
      getToken: 'token',
    })
  };

describe('## Create url ', function() {
    it('should create a url', token.required, function(done) {
      request(app)
        .post('/urls/create')
        .send(url)
        .end(function(err, res) {
        expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
        expect(res.body.author).to.equal('Alexey');
        url = res.body;
        done();
      });
    });
  });

});
```

When I run the unit test I get an error:

```
TypeError: next is not a function
      at Context.middleware (node_modules\express-jwt\lib\index.js:76:16)
```

I cannot understand why I get it. Help me, please !
I think that I created little the error which since can find.

***UPDATED***

`middlewares/token.js`:

```
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var config = require('../config');

function getTokenFromHeader(req){
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Token') {
        return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    }

    return null;
}

var token = {
    required: jwt({
        secret: config.get('jwtSecret'),
        userProperty: 'payload',
        getToken: getTokenFromHeader
    })
};

module.exports = token;
```

Comment: I posted my `middleware/token` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on your `it('should create a url', token.required, function(done)` line. Because the token is supposed to be a middleware, it requires the parameters `req`, `res`, and `next`.

In your test, you are not supplying the server with a token so you can remove the token.required from your test.

If you do make a test for the token authentication, however, you can get around this problem by calling `token.required` manually inside your test with your own `next` function. You would also need to supply the server with a jwt in your request.

Answer (score 0):

`it('should create a url', token.required, function(done) {`

Mocha tests don't allow the use of [Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) style middleware. Without that support, passing `token.required` to `it()` will invoke `token.required`. `jwt()` within `token.required` is attempting to invoke the callback `next` which, is part of the Connect middleware function args

```
const express = require('express')
const server = express()

server.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('this is middleware')
  return next() // Call next middleware 
})
```

You don't need to do this anyway considering you want to test the route. If the route is working properly it will require the key and will work. You can test that scenario by making a request without the JWT and assert that it fails via status code.